# пробелы при переносе данных из строки в массив c++

Tags: c++, массивы, c++-cli

Проблема такова: нужно, чтобы при считывании чисел из строки пробелы(случайное количество пробелов между числами) превращались в 1 пробел, а сами числа заносились в массив. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Ну замените в строке два последовательных пробела на один. Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно. Если числа должны заноситься в массив, то зачем превращать пробелы в единичные?

Ну да ладно. Хотя такое двойное использование функций противоречит всему, что говорится о хорошем тоне в проектировании - держите:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string handle(const string& src, vector<int>& v)
{
    istringstream in(src);
    ostringstream out;
    int i;
    while(in >> i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
        out << i << " ";
    }
    return out.str();
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;
    string res = handle("1   2 3      4  5       6",v);

    cout << res << endl;
    for(int i: v) cout << "[" << i << "]\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "сами пробелы превратились в один пробел" ? Это должно произойти в исходной строке/файле или надо сделать новую строку файл, или пробелы надо добавлять в массив?
Так как исходные условия задачи даны не полностью то попробую подсказать и того что ясно:

в цикле считываем всё посимвольно, и добавляем переменную "предыдущий символ", каждый раз после считывания символа, если это число, то добавляем в массив и устанавливаем в "предыдущий символ" = "добавленное число"
Если же это пробел, то не добавляем в массив и в "предыдущий символ" = "этот пробел", и в зависимости от не до конца предоставленного условия, например выводим этот пробел.
Если же это пробел и "предыдущий символ" тоже был пробел то в зависимости от исходного условия, которое не было предоставлено полностью, можно , например, ничего не делать.